How can we sort multiple values ​horizontally using VLOOKUP?
We send inspectors to stores once or maximum twice a month and we have a store scoring system.
Audit information is written on the home page, including the date on which the auditor went and where the auditor went.
Additionally, there is a page called scores, and on the score page, I can sort the scores and inspector names by store, using VLOOKUP, and the names of the inspectors by month in the column header.
HOMEPAGE



DATE
STORE NAME
PERSON
EMAIL
AUDITPOINT




01.01.2024
NEW YORK
JOHN DOE
JOHN@GMAIL.COM
100


11.01.2024
NEW YORK
JOHN DOE
JOHN@GMAIL.COM
80


03.01.2024
UTAH
JACK WILSON
JACK@GMAIL.COM
90


04.01.2024
NEVADA
JACK WILSON
JACK@GMAIL.COM
90


12.01.2024
NEVADA
JOHN DOE
JOHN@GMAIL.COM
75


01.02.2025
NEVADA
JOHN DOE
JOHN@GMAIL.COM
75



The page where the formula should be.
POINT
Search according to the current month of 01/01/2024, that is, audits between 01/01/2024` and 31/01/2024     D2 IS 01/01/2024



STORE
1. POINT
1. PERSON
2. POINT
2. PERSON
AVERAGE




NEW YORK
100
JOHN DOE
80
JOHN DOE
90


UTAH
90
JACK WILSON


90


NEVADA
90
JACK WILSON
75
JOHN DOE
82.5



Google Sheet Link : google sheet table

So you need a formula in the AUDIT POINT based on the store name and month/yr match with AUDIT HOMEPAGE data?!

Yes, I need a formula on the POINT page.
I manually added the required values ​​to the page named POINT, how can I do it only with the formula?


You may try:
=torow(sortn(filter({HOMEPAGE!$F:$F,HOMEPAGE!$D:$D},HOMEPAGE!$C:$C=$B10,eomonth(HOMEPAGE!$B:$B,)=eomonth(D$2,)),2,,1,))



How can I calculate all stores at once on a monthly basis? Do I need to write the formula for all stores one by one?

You could just drag the formula OR if you need a single array-style formula, apply the given logic within map/lambda

I don't know anything about lambda.
